# Dynamically create a form

Tags: jquery, forms, dynamic

I've got this:

```
    $('input[data-type="UserDetails"]').each(function(index, input){
        var name = $(input).attr('name');
        var value = $(input).is(":checked");
        alert('name: ' + name + ' value:' + value);
        });

        showForm = "<form><fieldset><legend>Headline here</legend><label>Name</label><input type='text' class='input-fluid' name='txtName'><label class='checkbox'><input type='checkbox'> Accept Terms & Conditions</label><button type='submit' class='btn'>Send</button></fieldset></form>";
```

The first thing is does is to check which checkboxes that was checked. And depending on that I want to add them to a form. Like if "checkbox for Text-field for name was checked". How is the smartest way to add them to the form "showForm"?

Could I use true/false statements inside "showForm"? And how is that being used in this situation?

Thankful for help!

Comment: building a form in one line ... *cringe!*

Comment: @Evan Yep, why not make a full website in one line? o_O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your form pre-built and give it a `display: none`. Once you've got this, implement the below function.

```
$('input[data-type="UserDetails"]').each(function(index, input){
        var name = $(input).attr('name');
        if($(input).is(":checked")){
            $("form").append('<input type="text" value="' + value + '" />');
        }
        });

 $("form").show(); // Show the form
```

Comment: It's not working, You've forgot to define the variable "value"... _cringe!_ .. **Just kidding** Thanks for your help! :)